# Optimize command issuing "'View is not base table" and "Corrupt" error messages

Tags: mysql, view, corruption

I have no experience with MySQL. My boss ran an `optimize` against a MySQL database. Against a bunch of views we got the message

> "tablexyz" is not BASE TABLE

and the next has message is

> Corrupt

It seems to be only against views, we didn't get any of these error messages against the base tables.

Does this look like an incorrect error message, or do we have issues with our tables?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot run [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) against a View. I can see why the error message would be `Corrupt`

In mysql, a view is represented as a table in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html).

I have discussed views in this light before

However, a View in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html) has `NULL` as a Storage Engine.

- `Mar 21, 2012` : [How do I get the execution plan for a view?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view/15375#15375)
- `Nov 23, 2011` : [How can I define the datatype of a view in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/how-can-i-define-the-datatype-of-a-view-in-mysql/8311#8311)

Consequently, there must be a storage engine to optimize on. Since the Storage Engine is NULL, `Corrupt` error message is understandable. Therefore, don't be concerned with the error message. Just run [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) on the underlying base tables.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this so started to look into it

`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablexyz;`

This produced something like

```
HEADER RESULT NAMES
View, Create View, character_set_client, collation_connection
```

And in the second column contained:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`%someone%`@`%some_ol_host_name%` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `tablexyz`.`view_tablexyz` AS 
SELECT `tablexyz`.`some_column_name`,
       `tablexyz`.`some_more_column_names`
FROM `tablexyz`
JOIN `tableabc` ON `tablexyz`.`id` = `tableabc`.`id`
WHERE `tablexyz`.`some_column_names` = 'somevalues'
GROUP BY  `tablexyz`.`some_column_names`;
```

For me... Well Turned out to be nothing but a view.

One last thing to note:

USE tablexyz;

```
ANALYZE TABLE tablexyz; -- Corrupt
CHECK TABLE tablexyz; -- OK
REPAIR TABLE tablexyz; -- Corrupt
```

Check table will provide a false positive as messages are inconsistent.

```
ANALYZE TABLE & REPAIR TABLE state that the table is corrupted even though it is a view.
```

And `CHECK TABLE` says the table is OK

```
# Table, Op, Msg_type, Msg_text
'tablexyz.tablexyz_view', 'check', 'status', 'OK'
```

Thought it odd but seems ok per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html#check-table-innodb)

Cheers,
Jay